# UCMA 4.0 How to get user name from PresenceNotificationRecieved Handler

Tags: c#, ucma

I am using UCMA 4.0 to get the presence status of a user. I have defined an event handler like so

```
    _remotePresenceView.PresenceNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<
        RemotePresentitiesNotificationEventArgs>(RemotePresence_PresenceNotificationReceived);
```

Its implementation is as follows:

```
// Event handler to process remote target's presence notifications
private void RemotePresence_PresenceNotificationReceived(object sender,
    RemotePresentitiesNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Presence notifications received for target {0}", <<How do I get the username here>>
        ));
    // Notifications contain all the notifications for one user.
    foreach (RemotePresentityNotification notification in e.Notifications)
    {
        if (notification.AggregatedPresenceState != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Aggregate State = "
                + notification.AggregatedPresenceState.Availability);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to delete the contact, delete the group, and unsubscribe to the "
        + "presence of the remote user.");

}
```

My question is how do I get the username for the person whos persence notification has changed in the event handler code?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `ContactCard` property on the `RemotePresentityNotification` class that will provide various details including `DisplayName` so in your case you will need to reference `notification.ContactCard.DisplayName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform an Active Directory lookup with a DirectorySearcher, by using the notification's PresentityUri property to cross-reference the AD "msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress" property for the user.